# Finding $[T]_A^B$ given a transformation $T(eX^2+fX+g)=(e+\alpha f, (1+\alpha)g)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: P_2(\mathbb{F}_4) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_4^2$ be given by:
$T(eX^2+fX+g)=(e+\alpha f, (1+\alpha)g)$, where $\mathbb{F}_4 = \{0,1,\alpha, 1 + \alpha\}$ with $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$. Find with justification:
a) $[T]_A^B$, where $A$ and $B$ are standard bases for $P_2(\mathbb{F}_4)$ and $\mathbb{F}_4^2$, respectively, b) a complete list of $ker(T)$ and $range(T)$.

So far I have plugged in values from A into the function and have a matrix looking like this:
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \alpha & 1+\alpha \\ 0 & 1+\alpha & 0 & 1+\alpha \end{bmatrix}

Is this enough for part a? From here I should be able to get part b.

Let me know if I am on the right track or if I am doing something wrong.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you think of $\mathbb{F}_4$? In the usual notation, $(e+\alpha f, (1+\alpha)g)\not\in\mathbb{F}_4$...

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this $T$ transformation goes from the set of polynomials over $F_4$ of degree at most 2 to ${F_4}^2$, the 2d space over $F_4$, no?

What values have you *plugged* in? You need to apply $T$ on the elements of the given basis $A$. It says, the standard basis, on $P_2(F_4)$, that is the 3 polynomials: $1,x,x^2$.
Ok, so calculate $T(1)$, $T(x)$ and $T(x^2)$, these will be the *columns* of the matrix. So, this is going to be a $3\times 2$ matrix.

For b) you don't really need the matrix. Try to show that any 2d vector is in the range of $T$ (for this, you don't need the fact that the field is $F_4$), and calculate which $(e,f,g)$ coefficients give $0$ when applied $T$.

Let $\beta:=\alpha+1$.

Comment: Sorry about that I did mean $\mathbb{F}_4^2$.  I plugged in the values of $\mathbb{F}_4$ into the polynomial expression, but what you have said makes more sense.

Comment: So for this a) I get that the matrix is \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1+\alpha \\  \alpha & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  Is that correct?

Comment: Well, it's usually meant the transpose: the results written in the *columns* (because the matrix multiplication $A\cdot B$ corresponds to the composition of linear maps $A\circ B$):
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \alpha & 1 \\ 1+\alpha & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
However, this all could be turned around, if composition would be meant from left to right (but that's not usual in this context)..

Comment: So to get the range(T) I would do the following: \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \alpha & 1 & e+\alpha f \\ 1+\alpha & 0 & 0 &(1+\alpha)g \end{bmatrix}.  And I would see that this would require that $e=f=g=1. Am I going about this correctly?

Comment: I still do not know how to get the range(T) or ker(T) from this.